# How to get the selected radio button value in Payment processing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to give payment processing option e wallet and cod in checkout page, with the help of radio button, but the selected value is not getting fetched in php. How can this be solved?

I could't upload my code, so I am explaining the required logic, please do help.

1. In payment process i need a radio button
2. Selected radio button value should be given to php, so that my further calculations will continue.
3. I am unable to get the value in to php.

**CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='cod']").click(function () {
            if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvPassport").show();

            } else {
                $("#dvPassport").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form method ="post">
    <label for="chkYes">
        <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="cod" />
        COD
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label for="chkNo">
        <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="cod" />
        E-Wallet
    </label>
    <hr />
    <button type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">        
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
</div>

<?php
    echo $com;
    echo $grand_total;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($grand_total <= $com) {
            $com = $com - $grand_total;

            $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE  commission SET total_commission=$com WHERE e_id = '".$_SESSION["e_id"]."'");

            echo $com;
            $total_pay = $com;
            echo $total_pay;

        } else {
            $newcom = $grand_total - $com;
            $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE  commission SET total_commission=$newcom WHERE e_id = '".$_SESSION["e_id"]."'");
            $total_pay = $newcom;

            echo $total_pay;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why not storing $('#chkYes').val(); and $('chkNo').val(); into vars and then send those to the php

Comment: When you created the radio button SET (one does not create a lone radio button), did you associate a single state variable with the entire set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't actually sent any variables to your php.

You can send the value of 'cod' by declaring a php var and assigning it the value via post, likewise for your txtPassportNumber, e.g.

```
 $cod =  $_POST['cod'];
 $passNo =  $_POST['txtPassportNumber'];
```

Include these php variables in your php file and then use them to continue with your calculations.

Hope this helps

Comment: you could instead pass the selected value via by a variable on submit, e.g. declare e.g. 'var codsel = $("input[type='radio'][name='cod']:checked"); '  in your script, and pass codsel instead. of cod:checked